# flutter json Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap

Tags: node.js, json, flutter

i'm new to flutter world and i got an error which i can't understand properly.

this is my netwrok handler code

```
Future get(String url) async {
    final String? token =await storage.read(key: "token");
    url = formatter(url);
    var response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(url),
      headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer $token"},
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200 || response.statusCode == 201) {
      log.i(response.body);
      return json.decode(response.body);
    }
    log.i(response.body);
    log.i(response.statusCode);   }
```

and this is my code where i'm calling network handler's get method

```
void checkProfile() async {
    var response = await networkHandler.get('/profile/checkProfile');
    print('here' + response );
    // if(response['status'] == true){
    //   print('here');
    //   setState(() {
    //     page = showProfile();
    //   });
    //
    // }else{
    //   setState(() {
    //     page = button();
    //   });
    // }

  }
```

and i'm getting this error

[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
E/flutter (23474): #0      _ProfileScreenTabState.checkProfile (package:blog_app/screens/tabview/profiletab_screen.dart:24:20)

can anybody please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass `Map` into a method that accepts `String` here:

`print('here' + response );`